# Pull Icon / Sync Pull and Push are incorrectly disabled in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

Today, the update to VS 22, version 17.7.3 was done.  Not likely a contributing factor, just saying VS was changed also.

The git repo was created remotely / locally within VS, push was successful to Git.

When NPM packages were updated and pushed, the expected alert that a package had a vulnerability and needed to be merged showed up.  Completed the merge on Git. So, there's an updated package on remote that needs to be pulled to the local repo.

Trying a push at this point, raises the alert that the local repo is behind the remote repo. git status -sb confirmed this and confirmed the remote repo was being tracked.

Doing the command line pull worked, however. Then the push worked.

There was no way to do the pull or sync pull and push with Git Changes, pull and push only worked via CMD window.  The icons in the Git Changes window are disabled.  So Git Changes seems to think all is up to date.

The CMD window was opened, drive / path set.  git pull and subsequently worked. Visual Studio git changes was clueless.

Here is the Git Changes window, with the Program.cs content shown, prior to any changes:

[image: File and Git Changes Prior to Edit]

The //Add comment ... will now be removed, here is the subsequent pic showing Git Changes:

[image: Line removed, Commit All Ready]

Local Commit is now done, Pull icon, Sync Pull and Push icon, should be enabled, right?:

[image: Edit made, commit all done, no icons in Git Changes]

However I can go to the command window and do the git pull, then the git push. As expected, all is up to date, no changes made remotely, nothing pushed yet:

[image: git pull done]

Screen shot after prior pull and push:

[image: Edit still in play]

Now, git push:

[image: Next git push]

And the program.cs file confirming the edit:

[image: Confirm line is removed with latest edit]

OK, so what's up with the Git Changes window?  The icons for Pull and the back-circular Sync Pull & Push should be enabled, right?

Again, the update to VS 17.7.3 was done earlier.  But I doubt this did anything to Git Changes, unless (a real stretch here) somehow a Git Changes dev edit crept in to the latest CI / CD, maybe?

The VS Project is the current Angular template.  This is being used to test out the workability of the various Security / Dependabot alerts.  In the process, it was noted the Git Changes window icons were always disabled.  The icons in other projects being tested were enabled when they should have been.  I have not rechecked those, however.

Could only locate Tags for git, github.  Nothing exists for VS except generic tags, nothing specifying Git Changes within VS.

Answer (score 0):

Survey says ...

[image: Sync pull and push, etc. are moved]

... looks like the options got moved to the Commit All drop down as options.  But still, why are the icons disabled if the drop down options work?

Update -- the options **don't** always work.  I downgraded/upgraded a nuget package version. (spa proxy) and noted using the pull and push sync option in the Commit All drop down did not work.

Got the error that the version was ahead by 1 on the remote.

Confirmed with git status -sb.  But could run pull then push from the command line and it all worked.

Refreshing Dependabot on the Dependency graph page confirmed it.  Prior to command line attempts, this did not update.  After command line attempts, it will update.

The answer applies as far as where the options exist.  But the CLI has to be used to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got with our lead at work.  Turns out using a mapped drive for a local repo isn't a very good idea. :)  That's the issue.

With a local repo on the local machine drive, everything works.

Should anyone else run into this one, here is what I did:

1. Kept the same folder structure / naming as on the mapped drive.
2. Cloned the git repo to the new drive.
3. Found upon getting branch status, etc. that dubious ownership was detected:

> C:\Training\DevOps-Git-Azure-Supply-Chain-Security\MyDemoSolution\MyDemoSolution>git
> branch -avv fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at
> 'C:/Training/DevOps-Git-Azure-Supply-Chain-Security/MyDemoSolution/MyDemoSolution'
> 'C:/Training/DevOps-Git-Azure-Supply-Chain-Security/MyDemoSolution/MyDemoSolution'
> is owned by:
> 'S-1-5-32-544' but the current user is:
> 'S-1-5-21-1485531944-4055646715-1410629759-44569' To add an exception for this directory, call:
>
> ```
>     git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Training/DevOps-Git-Azure-Supply-Chain-Security/MyDemoSolution/MyDemoSolution
> ```

Upon running the recommended command from git CLI, all was good.

The mapped drive repo location was a solution to working with a VM, company machine and my own machine at home.  Don't do the mapped drive solution ... :)