# Git Changes Pull, Sync Pull & Push icons always disabled

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

[image: Commit All Drop Down Contains These Options]

Please see my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77018693/pull-icon-sync-pull-and-push-are-incorrectly-disabled-in-visual-studio).

Looks like the down arrow / circle-back icon options also exist in the Commit All drop down as options. Why are these icons disabled if the drop down options are enabled?

The Commit All drop down options don't always work. I downgraded/upgraded a nuget package version. (spa proxy) Using options in the Commit All drop down to pull, or sync pull and push, did not cause a change of version in Dependabot / Dependencies tab.

At one point, got the error that the local and remote versions were not in sync. Confirmed with git status -sb.  Your mileage may vary -- the point is, something did change someplace for this to have happened along the way.

Only doing pull and push from the command line gets the version on the Dependencies tab to change.

Refreshing Dependabot on the Dependency graph page should confirm this.

Using the Commit All Drop Down options, Spa Proxy version on the Dependencies tab in the Dependency Graph did not update. Using the CLI, Spa Proxy version did update.

The answer in the referenced post is partly correct -- the disabled options also exist in the Commit All drop down. But the CLI has to be used to get anything to work.

To reproduce the error, do the following:

1. Set up an Angular Project in Visual Studio.  There is a Beta version, I used the latest stable version.  Also ensure the latest Visual Studio updates are applied, clear any notifications in Notifications.
2. Using the Create Repository option, drill to the folder that contains the VS solution.
3. Uncheck Create Private Repository.
4. Follow through on the options to create local / remote repositories.
5. In GitHub, set up Dependabot on the new repo, include version change alerts.
6. Choose any package, downgrade / upgrade the version, etc.
7. The down, and circle back arrows, will always be disabled despite changes in the remote or local repos.
8. Use a Command window, navigate to the folder containing the local repo.
9. Use the CLI commands to confirm the version in the Dependencies tab changes.
10. Performing the same version changes, use the drop down options from Commit All.  The error should be reproduced. It should be confirmed these do not affect the version in the Dependencies tab.

Those are the steps I'm using.  If anyone else can do this and it works ... well, it is a holiday weekend coming up.  Maybe I should just leverage it, watch college football and chill :).